# CA2000 and disposal of WCF client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, code-analysis, idisposable

There is plenty of information out there concerning WCF clients and the fact that you cannot simply rely on a using statement to dispose of the client.  This is because the Close method can throw an exception (i.e. if the server hosting the service doesn't respond).

I've done my best to implement something that adheres to the numerous suggestions out there.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(); // from service reference
  try
  {
    client.DoSomething();
  }
  finally
  {
    client.CloseProxy();
  }
}

public static void CloseProxy(this ICommunicationObject proxy)
{
  if (proxy == null)
    return;

  try
  {
    if (proxy.State != CommunicationState.Closed 
      && proxy.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
      proxy.Close();
    }
    else
    {
      proxy.Abort();
    }
  }
  catch (CommunicationException)
  {
    proxy.Abort();
  }
  catch (TimeoutException)
  {
    proxy.Abort();
  }
  catch
  {
    proxy.Abort();
    throw;
  }
}
```

This appears to be working as intended.  However, when I run Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010 I still get a CA2000 warning.

> CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In
>   method 'DoSomething()', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   'client' before all references to it
>   are out of scope.

Is there something I can do to my code to get rid of the warning or should I use SuppressMessage to hide this warning once I am comfortable that I am doing everything possible to be sure the client is disposed of?

Related resources that I've found:

- http://www.theroks.com/2011/03/04/wcf-dispose-problem-with-using-statement/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151755/Correct-WCF-Client-Proxy-Closing.aspx
- http://codeguru.earthweb.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c15941/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a call to `Dispose` in your `finally` block, after the call to `CloseProxy`. At that point you can be reasonably sure that `Dispose` won't throw, although it seems a bit silly to add superfluous code *just* to keep code analysis happy - I'd probably just suppress the message.

(Whichever option you choose, include very clear comments explaining why the code does what it does.)

Comment: The dispose method is not available on my auto-generated client.  Should it be?

Comment: If the `Dispose` method isn't available on your client then why is code analysis complaining that you're not calling it? The client may well have an explicit implementation of the `IDisposable` interface, in which case you could do something like `((IDisposable)client).Dispose` or, to be sure, `var d = client as IDisposable; if (d != null) d.Dispose;`.

Comment: I think I'm seeing the problem.  Code Analysis doesn't care what CloseProxy does.  If I put the call to CloseProxy in a try/finally where I close in the finally there is no warning.  If I make CloseProxy call close and nothing else, there is still a warning.  I think this warrants a suppress.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd do in this situation. CA2000 is notoriously difficult to satisfy; cries "wolf" much too often.